# Muffler fell off now has transmission issues

Tags: engine, transmission, exhaust, caravan, muffler

My 02 Dodge Caravan's muffler fell off sometime when I was heading to my girlfriends place. I didn't notice it till I got to her place because I listen to music loudly. Anyways I was driving it around for a couple days and everything was fine I hung the rest of the exhaust up with some wire to keep it from dangling. But now out of nowhere I'm having really bad transmission issues, the trans fluid is perfectly pink and at the correct level, the check engine came on and gave the codes P0700, P0731, P0732, P0733, and P0736.
Could this be all because of the muffler falling off?

The engine is the 3.3 V6 and the muffler has a resonator as well if that changes anything.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  What's the mileage on your Caravan?  Those are pretty infamous for having transmission issues around 200k (I know ours did).

Comment: It has 168,000kilometers

Comment: When did it last have a service -oil & filter change, plugs etc etc?

Comment: Just topped up the oil a couple weeks ago but it's been 6500 kilo's since last filter and oil change

Comment: Plugs I have no clue when those were last changed

Comment: *really bad transmission issues*  Could you define?

Comment: After driving for about a minute or so first gear doesn't work and a check engine light comes on all the codes except P0700 are saying the gear ratio for 1,2, 3 and reverse are incorrect

Comment: And what I mean by doesn't work is it doesn't engage I guess it just revs and then changes to second gear

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "muffler". If you mean the last part of the exhaust, behind the transmission and everything than it's probably just a coincidence.

But, if it happened to fall off and take the oxygen sensor, or the path upstream of the oxygen sensor with it you will have problems. It could also have leaked hot exhaust gases on the transmission, and if aimed at the right spot that could have melted harnesses or cause fluid to overheat, causing issues like you are having.